# What is the correct tense of a verb in a subordinate clause of the if-clause of a conditional sentence?

Tags: grammar, tense

I would like to know which is the correct one of the two (incomplete) sentences below:

a. If we decided to use a genuinely neutral notation in which the symbols did not carry any information, then we could not [...]

b. If we decided to use a genuinely neutral notation in which the symbols do not carry any information, then we could not [...]

Comment: Normal practice would be to follow the tense: **If we decided......did not carry...** and **If we decide......do not carry...**         The following examples may be helpful to you although they don't bear directly on your question:: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/conditional-sentences-was-instead-of-were/  https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/verbs-time-clauses-and-if-clauses

Comment: @Ronald Sole Thank you very much. I was hesitant because the property that the subordinate clause is about is something like a "timeless fact" and as Webster says: `there is the problem of the "continuing or timeless fact"-as in "Crime doesn't pay."  If we make this a subordinate clause with a main clause in the past tense, the commentators would have us follow natural sequence: "The Lone Ranger said that crime doesn't pay".' (Webster's Dictionary of English Usage: English Dictionary, p.838).

Comment: @Ronald Sole I would like to add to my previous comment another source of by doubts. This is the fact that the past tense in an if-clause is not a  proper past tense in the sense that it does not express the fact that something really happened in the past. It is only a formal tool to express a so-called improbable condition in order to formulate a conditional sentence.

Comment: I can't point to an infallible rule or authority in this area. But context is always the clue. How does one report the classic statement?: **He says the world is round**. The writer has to decide in each instance which tense of the verb best suits the purpose.

Comment: @Ronald Sole Thank you for your valuable help.